# How to get the width/height of a Canvas?

Tags: gwt

I'd like to have a canvas on my html page, with width = 100%. I'd like to then get the width in pixels of the canvas at runtime. Something like:

```
Canvas c = Canvas.createIfSupported();
c.setWidth("100%");
c.setHeight("100%");

// let's draw a rectangle to fill the whole canvas:
c.getContext2d().rect(0, 0, ?, ?); // <-- what's its actual width/height?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (surprisingly)

```java
c.getContext2d().rect(0, 0, 299, 149);
```

... no matter what the actual pixel size of the canvas is. The reason is, that 300x150 is the default **coordinate space** size, see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element

You can change this by using `canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth()` and `canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight()` to anything you want.

Often, people want to draw independently of the actual size of the canvas, so they just set the coordinate space to something like 100x100, and the drawn image gets scaled automatically.

However, you may want to find out about the actual canvas pixel size:

```java
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

  @Override
  public void execute() {

    final int clientWidth = canvas.getElement().getClientWidth();
    final int clientHeight = canvas.getElement().getClientHeight();

    setupCoordinateSpace(canvas, clientWidth, clientHeight);
    drawMyImage(canvas);
  }
});
```

Note, that this must be done in `scheduleDeferred`, because the client size will only be known after the browser had a chance to perform the layout.

You can use this information to adjust the aspect ratio to match the canvas (which I would recommend, because otherwise you get distorted images)

```java
void setupCoordinateSpace(Canvas canvas, int clientWidth, int clientHeight) {
  final double aspect = (double) clientWidth / (double) clientHeight;
  canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(
      (int) (myCoordinateSpaceWidth / aspect));
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can also set the coordinate space to match the pixel size, so you can perform pixel-exact drawing on an HTML5 canvas:

```java
void setupCoordinateSpace(Canvas canvas, int clientWidth, int clientHeight) {
  canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(clientWidth);
  canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(clientHeight);
}
```

After the coordinate space has been set up, you can call `drawMyImage()`

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer Chris, makes perfect sense. If the user alters the size of their browser during run time, I should probably update the coordinate space then right? (I figure there's an onWindowSizeChanged listener for that). Thank you!

Comment: @briceshatzer could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

use canvas width and height methods

```
var width = c.width;
var height = c.height;
```

Comment: Right but since I'm specifying the width/height as "100%", that doesn't seem to work? I want to know its size in pixels after the browser has finished inflating the canvas to 100% width/height.